# Columnizing a list with ANSI-color codes?

Tags: multiple-columns, zsh, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

Using `column` or `pr -T3` to columnize an input with ANSI escapes results in bad align of the items – they are under or overaligned. For example: `ls -1 --color=always|column`.

I'm writing a file manager and would want 2 columns format, like in Midnight Commander. The good part is that the project is written in Zsh script and I would want a nice way of columnizing color `fd .`/`exa -1 --color=always`/`ls -1 --color=always` output, including a Bash/Zsh/Awk/etc. script as a solution. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `zsh` builtin `print` can handle colors when creating columns with the `-C` and `-c` options.  The source code even has this note:

> ```
> * Prevent misaligned columns due to escape sequences by
> * skipping over them. Octals \033 and \233 are the
> * possible escape characters recognized by ANSI.
> ```

Converting the command output to arguments for `print` can be slightly tricky, but this combination of a command substitution with `$(...)` and an expansion split by line  using `${(f)...}` should work:

```
print -C 2 ${(f)"$(ls -1 --color=always)"}
```

You also can pass in data via a [coprocess](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86372/).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tecolicom/App-ansicolumn is probably the tools you are looking for. The author has an ansifold and other utilities on gihub and CPAN.